# Facebook api taggable_friends's gender

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get taggable_friends's gender on v2.0 of Facebook Api but there are only "id", "first_name", "last_name", "middle_name","name" and "picture" fields as acceptable params. I used v2.0 because otherwise I couldn't get larger pictures of taggable_friends.

FB.api('/me/taggable_friends?fields=id,name,gender,picture.width(500)', function (response) {});

Comment: There is no gender. Why would you need gender to tag someone?

Comment: Actually, I need to take user's a few friends with large profile picture,name and gender. How can I get them with another way? 
FB.api('/me/frineds') only gives who already use the app .

Comment: Taggable_friends are only for tagging. For anything else you use /me/friends. Doesn't matter if you don't get all friends

Comment: I have to find a few friends of users, /me/friends returns empty for If any of friends doesn't use the app.

Comment: I'm just telling you what is possible